# creating suitable dataframe from api

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, pyspark

I have this api link where I want to create a dataframe. so far, I have performed the following steps:

response = requests.get("https://example.com/api")

data = response.json()

df = df.DataFrame(data)

df.head()

```
took   | total   | results
3      |  985    | {'AA': '3', 'AC': '1', 'BI': [], 'CY': 'DE', '...}
3      |  985    | {'AA': '8', 'AC': '1', 'BI': [], 'CY': 'DE', '...}
3      |  985    | {'AA': '8', 'AC': '2', 'BI': ['280000'], 'CY':'NL', '...}
```

However, I'm interested in the content of results. I want it to be like this:

```
'AA' | 'AC' | 'BI' | 'CY'
'3'  | '1'  | null | 'DE'
'8'  | '1'  | null | 'DE'
'8'  | '2'  | '280000' | 'NL'
```

Any heads up on how I can proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some luck looking into [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) but given the df you already have, you could read the results column in as records, and then fix the BI column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'took': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 3},
 'total': {0: 985, 1: 985, 2: 985},
 'results': {0: {'AA': '3', 'AC': '1', 'BI': [], 'CY': 'DE'},
  1: {'AA': '8', 'AC': '1', 'BI': [], 'CY': 'DE'},
  2: {'AA': '8', 'AC': '2', 'BI': ['280000'], 'CY':'NL'}}})

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.results.values)
df['BI'] = df['BI'].apply(lambda x: x[0] if x else np.nan)
```

Output

```
  AA AC      BI  CY
0  3  1     NaN  DE
1  8  1     NaN  DE
2  8  2  280000  NL
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Chris. I have finally landed myself into a more concise approach. See my answer below:

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad to say that after lots of research, I got to a solution.

```
response = requests.get("https://example.com/api")
data = response.json()
```

Exploring the structure of the returned JSON object by looking at

```
data.keys()
```

yielded

> dict_keys(['took', 'total', 'results'])

Since I am interested in "results", I created my df on the "return" key

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data["results"])
df.head()
```

This returned my expected dataframe

```
       AA    AC    BI     CY
  0     3     1   NaN     DE
  1     8     1   NaN     DE
  2     8     2  280000   NL
```